# Stop sound in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"static" ofType:@"caf"]; 
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

I have implemented above code in my application.

It works perfectly, but the problem is I don't know how to stop it.

i.e Sound is of 10 sec.

Before 10 sec. if user taps button, sound should be stopped? How can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID, it stops sounds immediately.  You'll need to recreate the sound if you intend to use it again.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following instruction for disposes of a system sound object and associated resources:

```
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the AVFoundation framework. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMba_c-VSkI) is an amazing tutorial on how to play, pause, and stop sound using the AVAudioPlayer.