# Playing/Pausing sound in an iPhone app

Tags: ios, audio

Is there any way to stop the audio playing here? Like a play/stop kind of thing?

```
 -(IBAction)PlaySound:(id)sender{

audioTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Audio %@", audioInteger];
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundfileURLREF;
soundfileURLREF = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) audioTitle, CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
UInt32 SoundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundfileURLREF, &SoundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [stop sound in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512121/stop-sound-in-iphone)

Comment: Step one: stop using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound and get yourself a real sound player (i.e. AVAudioPlayer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple play/pause/stop example using the AVAudioPlayer class.

Create playing in viewDidLoad:

```
var audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("bach1", ofType: "mp3")

    var error : NSError? = nil

    player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: audioPath!), error: &error)
```

Inside play button:

```
player.play()
```

Inside pause button:

```
player.pause()
```

Inside stop button:

```
player.stop()
player.currentTime = 0;
```

Comment: @BenHeyderman did this help you, or did you need more clarification?